# How to prune down an almost leafless 8’ indoor avocado tree without killing it?

Tags: pruning

I have an 8’ tall indoor avocado pear tree which has only got a handful of leaves on the very top. The plant is under a skylight.

The whole stem of the tree is very dry and has no branches or leaves.Only about 2” of the stem at the very top right next to the leaves is green.

I would like to cut the plant right down without killing it. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Avocado's want to be trees and unlike some other plants they do not stay small when grown in pots.  They exhibit [apical dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apical_dominance) and will usually regrow from the top of the stem no matter where you  cut it.

Find out where live tissue is by peeling back a tiny section of the stem.  If it looks alive you can cut it there with a sharp instrument.

Increase light and reduce water until new growth appears.

Comment: Increase light: under a skylight that would mean raising the pot closer to the skylight?

Comment: @Jasen moving closer to a window is a lot less work!